# How can I eliminate the verification process for Microsoft products on macOS?

Tags: ms-office, google-chrome, verify

Whenever I open any Office 365 for macOS product (like Outlook), it takes a long time for it open (up to 5 Minutes), because Apple runs a "verification" process; same happens in Chrome, Skype and other MS products. I do web-site checking and translations, so I need these programs on my Mac and work with them.

How can I get rid of this more than annoying process?

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail: what Mac; what OS version? Are you on the latest version of 365? Does this happen every time you launch the apps? What exactly happens? 5 minutes to launch an app is not normal by any means.

Comment: If it also happens with Chrome, it most likely isn‘t related to one specific vendor only. How did you install the applications in question, and where?

Comment: Are you by chance starting these apps from a DMG instead of directly from the Applications folder?

Answer (score -3):

By eliminating MS products, for instance.
I don't escatly know what you're doing with those programs, but I guess there are other non-MS softwares to do the same things. Get informed about that.